# struts2 spring plugin - it complains about getBean() of WebApplicationContext not being found

Tags: spring, struts2, struts, spring-3, struts2-spring-plugin

I am using `Struts 2.2.3.1` and using `Struts2-spring plugin 2.2.3.1` with it. The dependency injections are working fine, but my use of `ApplicationContext`'s `getBean` method is breaking :

```
WebApplicationContext ac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(context);
AdminService service = ac.getBean(AdminService.class);
```

This is how I used to inject dependencies into my Struts project using `Spring 3.0.6` (`AdminService` is a bean declared in `applicationContext.xml`. But now, with the addition of this plugin, it gives the following error :

> cannot find symbol symbol  : method
>   getBean(java.lang.Class)
>   location: interface
>   org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext

If I remove this plugin, then it works. What's the reason ?

Comment: Prior to Spring 3, the WebApplicationContext did not have the method you are trying to use, which leads me to believe that this is a classloading issue.  So it would appear that either your deployable's WEB-INF contains an older version of Spring, or your server is loading an older version from its own libs or another app.  Use something like 7-zip to pop open your WAR file and make sure that it contains the correct Spring jar.  Also, what server are you using?

Comment: Thanks.. Actually, Struts2-spring plugin 2.2.3.1 had some pre-Spring 3 dependencies.. which were being retrieved by Maven..When I upgraded to 2.3.1.2 version of the plugin, (which I assume, has been upgraded for Spring 3).. the code compiled properly

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working :D